# Finding Exact Screen Dimensions

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0

Totally new to iOS OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm trying to precisely identify the boundaries of my screen (iPad) by drawing a simple rectangle. From what I have found, it looks to me like the dimensions of an iPad screen are 768 x 1024. However, my screen is not being covered correctly (note that I am drawing in landscape mode if that matters).

I'm not sure of the interaction between the vertices and how I'm using the projection matrix command.

'self.baseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, FRAME_WIDTH*2, 0, FRAME_HEIGHT*2, 0, 0);'

If I delete this line, my rectangle renders with the lower left at the origin. But if I leave it in, it seems to render from the lower left, but the dimensions are too large and I can't seem to figure out how to change them predictably.

As you can see, I'm very confused. What is the best way of getting the exact screen dimensions. I need this to properly place other objects on the screen. Thanks!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
    GLKVector2 textureCoordinates;
} VertexData;

#define FRAME_HEIGHT 768.0f
#define FRAME_WIDTH 1024.0f

VertexData vertices[] = {
    { {       0.0f,         0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f} },   // bottom left
    { {FRAME_WIDTH,         0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f} },   // bottom right
    { {       0.0f, FRAME_HEIGHT, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f} },   // top left
    { {       0.0f, FRAME_HEIGHT, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0f} },   // top left
    { {FRAME_WIDTH,         0.0f, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f} },   // bottom right
    { {FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, 0.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f} }    // top right
};

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) EAGLContext *context;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GLKBaseEffect *baseEffect;

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    GLuint _vertexBufferID;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *) self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    self.baseEffect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.baseEffect.useConstantColor = YES;
    self.baseEffect.constantColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    self.baseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, FRAME_WIDTH*2, 0, FRAME_HEIGHT*2, 0, 0);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), offsetof(VertexData, positionCoordinates));

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - GKLView delegate methods

- (void) glkView: (GLKView *) view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.baseEffect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

- (void) update {

}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you using FRAME_HEIGHT * 2?

Comment: Because I read that one point = 2 pixels. Also by trial and error, this came the closest to filling the screen, but it's far less than perfect. Basically, this is a really noob attempt that I'm sure will be either modified or discarded when I figure this out.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean by "closest to filling the screen?"

Comment: As I look at the effect of this specifically, I think that is the issue. If I cover my rectangle with a texture, I can see that it is centered accurately (without the *2). When I do the *2 again, now I can see that my rectangle appears to cover only the lower left quadrant of the screen, so it looks like that it exactly the problem. Not sure what else I was toggling earlier, but isolating just that part seems to reveal the problem. Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use FRAME_HEIGHT and FRAME_WIDTH, not twice them.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the screen dimensions with:

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
```

however, be wary of using this during application start-up.

To get the orientation of the current view controller:

```
[UIViewController interfaceOrientation]
```

To obtain the device orientation:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

... or ...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

In your case, you can simply use the bounds of EAGLView that you have:

```
CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I pass this over to my vertices? My vertex array is defined globally. If I draw a rectangle, I have to know these coordinates in advance. Do I just draw a unit square and then scale it or how does one go about this? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you *have* to define your vertex array globally? Its easier if you don't. . . however, if you must you could define a CGSize pointer and have the array reference it. . . then update it after the viewDidLoad. . btw: Try to get an understanding of the difference between these important view properties: bounds and frame (you can google it). . . they're really important foundation concepts when you're starting out.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just the way that I've seen it done most frequently, so I was trying to follow what I thought was the most commonly accepted procedure. Thanks for the tip on bounds vs frame. I'll look into it.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not an expert on OpenGL best practices. . I just meant that it would be easier to make the array from within an instance because you could just pass in size.width and size.height into your vertex array. . rather than setting up the array first, and then manipulating it once you know the sizes.